# Fontawesome can't load icon by reference number in css

Tags: css, asp.net-core, font-awesome

This is similar to the 'icon appears as a square' question, however mine works when using 'fa fa-child' etc, but not when I use the image reference id.

In my layout I have:

```
 <link href="~/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/my-css.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme">
```

css:

```
.my-button {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#585858,#8C8C8C)
}

.my-button-blue:before {
    content: "\f500";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Only using "\f500" in my css breaks it (it just shows a square), however using it in the code as below works fine:

```
<i class="fas fa-smile fa-2x text-white"></i>
```

I have also tried @import"../vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"; in my-css

I am tying to use it as part of my background image so that it 'crops' when reaching the  edge - sort of like a watermark.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/as8L924e/2/

Although this shows no icons...

Comment: Are you able to replicate this using a fiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <environment include="Development"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
     </environment>

Use :font-family:
         .my-button-blue:before {
            content: "\f500";
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
    font-weight: 900;
            font-size: 20px;
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense, but it hasn't fixed the problem :(

Comment: Do u have a refto the CDN ? >> && try to add>  font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 20px; <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: tried that instead of my local one - didn't make a difference

Comment: remove your  local CSS use the CDN  then , add size & weight as in updated answer

Comment: I have tried the CDN one instead of local - makes no difference. Unfortunately I cannot use it in production anyway as my site is in an offline environment. My updated code now has font-weight and font-size as above.

Comment: & do not use  all.min at develop

Comment: All working now - guess my case wasn't clearing proper over the last change, Thanks!

Comment: Why do I not use all.min during development?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure without codepen or something, but I think the problem might with `font-family`, because in `all.min.css` ff is set as `.fas{font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free"}`. So you might want to try change font family to this value in your code as well.

If you check what is inside the fontawesome file `all.min.css`, you will see that the font-face is defined as

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:900;
    font-display:auto;
    src:url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot);
    src:url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
        url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"),
        url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff) format("woff"),
        url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype"),
        url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}
```

Keep in mind, that if you install newer version of fa to your vendor, your code might broke.

Answer (score 0):

With help of developer console of modern browser, you can check what all css properties are being applied to the icon with class. You can use those css properties to define own classes and use them as you want.

Here is sample for it.

```
.my-button-blue:before {
  content: "\f500";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Below is the working code snippet for reference.

```css
.my-button-blue:before {
  content: "\f500";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fas fa-smile fa-2x text-white"></i>

<i class="my-button my-button-blue"></i>
```

Happy coding. :)

Comment: I've been looking at the css like that - and it looks fine. its just that my icon is a weird square instead of a smile. Thanks for the extra css.